# Copy from Excel to specific location in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm copying a range of cells from Excel as a picture to a Word document. It pastes at the beginning of the document.
How could I paste in a specific area? The area could be denoted by some text that I'd later find/replace.

```
Range("A1:H5").Select
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("MyFile.docx")

objWord.Visible = True

Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

I just came accross the same problem and used the following code. I use a bookmark called "here" which is saved in my Word document. HTH, Mitch.

```
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

Set WordApp = New Word.Application
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("MyFile.docx")

Range("A1:H5").Select
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("here").Select
Set objSelection = WordApp.Selection
objSelection.Paste
```