# VBA Excel -> Add picture below page number

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, report

I have a little picture that I would like to add into my word document, with Excel VBA. The thing is that it is not a problem to add it to the footers. But I would like to add it below the page number which i illustrated in the picture.

[image]

I have tried many things and used google to find inspiration. However, I cannot find any solution which solves this kind of problem. Do anyone have an idea to solve this?

Set B2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("P2")

```
With wApp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add()
    With wdDoc
        With wApp.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
            .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.5)
            .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
            .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(4.7)
            .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.5)
            .HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(0.98)
            .FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
        End With
        B2.Copy
        With .Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
            .Font.Size = 7
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            With .ParagraphFormat
                .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
                .TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(7), Alignment:=wdAlignTabRight
            End With
            .InsertAfter "THIS IS THE COMPANY IN THE LFT PART OF FOOTERS" & vbTab & "Page "
            .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False
            .InsertAfter Text:=" / "
            .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES", PreserveFormatting:=False
            .InsertAfter Chr(11) & vbTab
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .Paste
            .End = .End + 1
            With .InlineShapes(1)
                .LockAspectRatio = True
                .Height = InchesToPoints(0.25)
            End With
```

Kind regards

Mathias

Comment: You will find part of your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146052/vba-copy-as-image-from-excel-and-paste-into-word

Comment: Using an inline picture will force the footer text higher up on the page. If the footer must remain in position, the picture would have to be pasted as a floating picture. What is your preference?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
With .Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    .Font.Size = 7
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    With .ParagraphFormat
      .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
      .TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(7), Alignment:=wdAlignTabRight
    End With
    .InsertAfter "THIS IS THE COMPANY IN THE LFT PART OF FOOTERS" & vbTab & "Page "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False
    .InsertAfter Text:=" / "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES", PreserveFormatting:=False
    .InsertAfter Chr(11) & vbTab
    .Characters.Last.Paste
    .End = .End + 1
    With .InlineShapes(1)
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      .Height = InchesToPoints(0.25)
    End With
End With
```

Comment: I tried it, but a message box appers with the following text:

"Run-time error '-2147023170 (800706be)': Automation error"

When I push the debug button the following line of code turns into yellow:

".Characters.Last.Paste"

Comment: It works for me with a shape object copied from Excel. You need to explain what the 'B2' in 'B2.Copy' refers to.

Comment: B2 is: Dim B2 as Shape

Then I used set:

Set B2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("The Name of the Shape in Excel")

Comment: In that case, I can see no reson for the code failing; as I said, it works just fine for me. Instead of '.Characters.Last.Paste' you might try '.Collapse wdCollapseEnd' followed by '.Paste'

Comment: I have tried the  '.Collapse wdCollapseEnd' followed by '.Paste'. However, it is now the '.Paste' part that turned into yellow and again with the same error message.

I have tried to edit the lines of code from where I defined the code and added your part. Is it possible to see what is wrong?

Comment: I'd suspect either a faulty Office installation or a rogue third-party addin. Try repairing Office. If that doesn't resolve the problem, try running Office in Safe mode. If it works in Safe mode, a rogue third-party addin is the most likely cause.

Comment: I tried to unplug the addins and running my Macro in Safe Mode. None of those methods did work. I then have no idea to solve this problem, with the currently method that I am using. Do you have another idea to solve this problem?  Maybe another hint?

Comment: I did not say to 'unplug' your addins, but I did say to repair the Office installation, which you give no indication of having done.